# Is it possible to more accurately measure SVG text height?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to measure the exact height used to render a given string with a given font with an SVG text tag.

I've tried using `getBBox` and `getExtentOfChar`, but the height returned by both of these includes some extra space above (and sometimes below) the actual text rendered.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Typography_Line_Terms.svg
Using the terms in this image, I'm trying to get the either the cap height + descender height of the text being rendered. Or, if that's not possible, just the cap height. Is there a good way to calculate these values?

Here's a quick codepen showing the extra space I'm talking about:
http://codepen.io/pcorey/pen/amkGl

HTML:

```
<div>
  <svg><text>Hello</text></svg>
  <svg><text>Age</text></svg>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('svg').each(function() {
    var svg = $(this);
    var text = svg.find('text');
     
    var bbox = text.get(0).getBBox();
    svg.get(0).setAttribute('viewBox',
                           [bbox.x,
                            bbox.y,
                            bbox.width,
                            bbox.height].join(' '));
  });
});
```

I understand that this is a fairly font-specific thing, so this might be totally impossible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All the SVG DOM methods (`getBBox()`, `getExtentOfChar()`) are defined to return the full glyph cell height.  That extra space above the cap height is allowance for taller glyphs - such as accented capitals. I think this is true for HTML DOM methods as well.

There are, however, JS libraries around which may be of use. For example:

https://github.com/Pomax/fontmetrics.js

I have not used this library myself, so I can't tell you how reliable or accurate it is.

Comment: Alright, thanks. It looks like you can calculate the descent height  by rendering the text at y=0 and subtracting the bbox's y offset from its height (assuming dominant-baseline is set to alphabetical). There's still no way to get the ascent height or the cap height though... Bummer.

Comment: Did you find a solution @pcorey ?